# Sessions and cookies not getting created in React + Node.js backend

Tags: reactjs, node.js, postgresql, session

I have a react app that makes use of the following api to interact with my database but the sessions are not saved in the browser. I rechecked the code several times but cannot locate the error.

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import pg from "pg";
import cors from "cors";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import passport from "passport";
import { Strategy as LocalStrategy } from "passport-local";
import session from "express-session";
//import pgSession from "connect-pg-simple";
import env from "dotenv";
env.config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.API_PORT;


// Middleware 


  // Configure session middleware
  app.use(
    session({
     /*  store: new PGStore({
        conString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      }), */
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      cookie: { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, // 30 days
    })
  );
  

// PostgreSQL configuration
const db = new pg.Client({
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  });

  db.connect();

  //const PGStore = pgSession(session);
  
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cors());

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());


// Login endpoint
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Login successful', user: req.user });
});

// Logout endpoint
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.json({ message: 'Logout successful' });
});

// Register endpoint
app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
  try {
    await db.query('INSERT INTO users_table (user_email, user_password) VALUES ($1, $2)', [email, hashedPassword]);
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error encountered in api_server.js : ${error}`);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error registering user' });
  }
});

// Protected endpoint (requires authentication)
app.get('/protected', (req, res) => {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.json({ message: 'You are authenticated', user: req.user });
  } else {
    res.status(401).json({ message: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
});
// API endpoints for CRUD operations


//render all notes for the selected user
app.get('/notes/show/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    var user = parseInt(req.params.id);
    //console.log(`user = ${user}`);
    const result = await  db.query("SELECT * FROM notes_table join users_table on user_id = users_table.id  WHERE users_table.id = $1 order by note_id;",[user]);
    res.json(result.rows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching notes:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error fetching notes' });
  }
});

//Route to add notes
app.post('/notes/add/:id/', async (req, res) => {
  const { title, content, status } = req.body;
  //const q = req.body;
  const user = parseInt(req.params.id);
  //console.log(title);

  try {
    await db.query('INSERT INTO notes_table (user_id, note_title, note_content, datetimedetails) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)', [user, title, content, status]);
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Note added successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error encountered in api_server.js : ${error}`);
    //console.error('Error adding note:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error adding note' });
  }
});

//Route to delete notes
app.delete('/notes/delete/:user_id/:note_id', async (req, res) => {
  const user = parseInt(req.params.user_id);
  const noteId = parseInt(req.params.note_id);
  try {
    await db.query('DELETE FROM notes_table WHERE user_id = $1 AND note_id = $2', [user, noteId]);
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Note deleted successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error encountered in api_server.js : ${error}`);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error deleting note' });
  }
});

//Route to edit notes
app.patch('/notes/edit/:user_id/:note_id', async (req, res) => {
  const user = parseInt(req.params.user_id);
  const note = parseInt(req.params.note_id);
  const { title, content, status } = req.body;
  console.log(`selectedNote is ${note}`);
  try {
    await db.query('UPDATE notes_table SET note_title = $1, note_content = $2, datetimedetails = $3  WHERE note_id = $4 and user_id = $5', [title, content,status,note,user]);
    res.status(201).json({ message: 'Note updated successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Error encountered in api_server.js : ${error}`);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error updating note' });
  }
});



passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(async (username, password, done) => {
    try {
      const result = await db.query(
        "SELECT id, user_password FROM users_table WHERE user_email = $1",
        [username]
      );
      if (result.rows.length > 0) {
        const user = result.rows[0];
        if (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.user_password)) {
          return done(null, user);
        } else {
          console.log("User password incorrect");
          return done(null, false);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("User not found");
        return done(null, false);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      done(error);
    }
  })
);

// Serialize user
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

// Deserialize user
/* passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const result = await db.query("SELECT id FROM users_table WHERE id = $1", [
      id,
    ]);
    if (result.rows.length > 0) {
      done(null, result.rows[0]);
    } else {
      done(new Error("User not found"));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    done(error);
  }
}); */

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});



// Start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

I am expecting a browser based session and cookies but cannot establish the same. Any help would be appreciated. How can I go a step further to implement sessions on my database(Postgres)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).